# Get the latest value on each date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with the following structure:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
    IdColumn INT,
    DateColumn DATETIME 
)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
    IdColumn INT,
    DateColumn DATETIME,
    Value NUMERIC(18,2)
)
```

What i want to do is get the latest value from table2 having a less or equal date in table1.

This is the query i build:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
    IdColumn INT,
    DateColumn DATETIME 
)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
    IdColumn INT,
    DateColumn DATETIME,
    Value NUMERIC(18,2)
)


DECLARE @RefDate DATETIME='2012-09-01'
DECLARE @NMonths INT
DECLARE @MonthsCounter INT=1

SELECT @NMonths=DATEDIFF(MM,'2012-09-01','2013-03-01')


WHILE @MonthsCounter<=@NMonths  
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Table1
    SELECT 1,@RefDate

    SET @RefDate=DATEADD(MM,1,@RefDate);
    SET @MonthsCounter+=1;

END

INSERT @Table2

SELECT 1,'2012-09-01',1000
UNION
SELECT 1,'2012-12-01',5000
UNION
SELECT 1,'2013-01-01',3000



SELECT
T1.IdColumn,
T1.DateColumn,
T2.Value
FROM @Table1 T1

LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2
ON T2.IdColumn=T1.IdColumn AND T1.DateColumn>=t2.DateColumn
```

The problem is when a new value comes with a more recent date, i get all values until that date.

```
IdColumn    DateColumn              Value
----------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           2012-09-01 00:00:00.000 1000.00
1           2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 1000.00
1           2012-11-01 00:00:00.000 1000.00
1           2012-12-01 00:00:00.000 1000.00
1           2012-12-01 00:00:00.000 5000.00
1           2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 1000.00
1           2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 5000.00
1           2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 3000.00
1           2013-02-01 00:00:00.000 1000.00
1           2013-02-01 00:00:00.000 5000.00
1           2013-02-01 00:00:00.000 3000.00
```

The desired output is this one:

```
IdColumn    DateColumn              Value
----------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           2012-09-01 00:00:00.000 1000.00
1           2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 1000.00
1           2012-11-01 00:00:00.000 1000.00
1           2012-12-01 00:00:00.000 5000.00
1           2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 3000.00
1           2013-02-01 00:00:00.000 3000.00
```

How can i solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: It possible you have 3 rows with the same hour, minute, second? Or you don't save these information?

Comment: It is possible to have one row per date, dates are unique.

Comment: But in your dataset sample you have more rows with the same date. So, if you have the same date for a lot of rows, so you must use a subquery with a top function, otherwise, you can use a subquery without it and evaluate only on the base of date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select top 1 value
        from @table2 t2
        where t2.idColumn = t1.idColumn and
              t2.dateColumn <= t1.dateColumn
        order by t2.dateColumn desc
       ) t2value
from @table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am just posting Gordon's Answer with correct syntax :

```
select t1.*,
       (select top 1 value
        from @table2 t2
        where t2.IdColumn = t1.IdColumn and
              t2.DateColumn <= t1.DateColumn
        order by t2.DateColumn desc
       ) t2value
from @table1 t1
```

Comment: You could've just told him.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you fixed Gordon's code that's why i voted you up. But since you're answer is a fix of Gordon's code i think it's fair to mark is answer as the correct one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After comment, try this:

```
INSERT INTO #Table1 (IdColumn, DateColumn)
SELECT IdColumn, DateColumn
FROM #Table2 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 'X'
        FROM #Table2 tcopy
        where t.IdColumn = tcopy.IdColumn
        and convert(date, t.DateColumn) = convert(date, tcopy.DateColumn)
        and tCopy.DateColumn > t.DateColumn
    )
```

I used ">" because you told me, there are no rows with the same date/time in your table2